# Backend pages not loading correctly

Tags: php, magento

On Magento CE edition 1.9.2.2, I can't see certain navigation pages such as Category and Manage Stores. I've checked the system log files and see the following error:

```
[29-Oct-2015 17:49:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addAttributeToSelect() on a non-object in /home1/aust/public_html/WEBSITENAME/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Category.php on line 42
[29-Oct-2015 17:50:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object in /home1/aust/public_html/WEBSITENAME/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php on line 212
```

[image: Magento, New Store]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I had this happen sometimes after installing new modules - log out and log back solved it for me.

Comment: The issue here is it's trying to access a property of an object that couldn't be found. It's likely caused by an extension. The logging out/back in the admin only works if you've just installed a new extension, and it's typically a 404 or blank screen which doesn't show the page title. What extensions are installed?

Comment: No extensions added, straight out of the box installation. Logged out and in again,no joy.

Comment: If this is straight out of the box, then something is wrong.  Check all the files were extracted and uploaded correctly to the system.  When you're happy they are, wipe the database and install again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Re-installed twice and second time worked perfectly. Thank you all. How can I mark as resolved please?